# How does clang differ from gcc in how it finds declarations

Tags: c++, clang, clang++

I have an util.h/.cpp with an overload of operator>> for istreams which looks like

```
// util.h
//
// ... lots of stuff ...

std::istream& operator>>(std::istream& is, const char *str);
std::istream& operator>>(std::istream& is, char *str);
```

And

```
// util.cpp
//
// lots of stuff again
//! a global operator to scan (parse) strings from a stream
std::istream& operator>>(std::istream& is, const char *str){
  parse(is, str); return is;
}
//! the same global operator for non-const string
std::istream& operator>>(std::istream& is, char *str){
  parse(is, (const char*)str); return is;
}
```

in some other file I use this construct like this:

```
std::istream file;
char *x, *y;

// opening and allocating space for strings comes here

file >> "[ " >> x >> "," >> y >> " ]";
```

This worked perfectly well with gcc/g++ (v. 4.6.3) but now I wanted to use clang (v 3.0) and got errors stating, that the appropriate operator overloading can not be found:

```
clang -ferror-limit=1 -g -Wall -fPIC -o ors.o -c ors.cpp
ors.cpp:189:21: error: invalid operands to binary expression ('std::istream' (aka 'basic_istream<char>') and 'const char [2]')
   file >> "[ " >> x >> "," >> y >> " ]";
   ~~~~ ^ ~~~~
/usr/bin/../lib/gcc/x86_64-unknown-linux-gnu/4.6.3/../../../../include/c++/4.6.3/istream:121:7: note: candidate function
  not viable: no known conversion from 'const char [2]' to '__istream_type &(*)(__istream_type &)' for 1st argument;
  operator>>(__istream_type& (*__pf)(__istream_type&))
 [[ lots of other possible candidates from the stl ]]
```

Why is clang unable to find the appropriate declaration, while gcc has no problems. How can I fix this?

Comment: Can you show us what you've `#include`d in each file?  Perhaps the g++ implementation is including another header that clang isn't.

Comment: it is always advisable to post a small compilable code sample when You are asking questions about different behaviors from compilers.

Comment: I'll try to get a minimal compileable example.

Comment: I'm pretty sure the standard doesn't allow you to overload any operator only involving standard library or built-in types. That said, operators are located in namrspaces associated with the arguments. The only such namespace is namespace `std` which, indeed, doesn't have a shift operator overloaded taken the arguments you are passing.

Comment: It is impossible to even instantiate `std::istream` (it is an abstract class)... so ?

Comment: You did not put your overloads in the global namespace, did you?

Comment: @DietmarKühl You can legally provided overloads in such cases (since standard library types are treated exactly like user defined types) however you have to rely on something other than ADL for lookup, since ADL would require placing the overloads in the `std` namespace which is prohibited. This can be done with, e.g., a _using-declaration_.

Comment: @bames53: according to 13.5.2 paragraph 1 the look-up rules for the operator are governed by 13.3.1.2 (as there are overloaded member and non-member functions). According to 13.3.1.2 paragraph 3 the overload set for the non-member function is build according to 3.4.2. Finally, 3.4.2 (cunningly named [basic.lookup.argdep]; you might guess what comes next) paragraph 2 states that using declarations don't contribute to the overload set. Although you are right that you can overload the functions in the global namespace these functions shall never be found using operator notation.

Comment: @DietmarKühl The portion I think you're referring to states that "_using-declarations_ used to specify the types" don't contribute to the set found by ADL. In this case the using-declaration is not one used to specify the type, nor do we consider only names found by ADL. Paragraph 3 states that the set of names found is the union of names found by ADL and by unqualified lookup (3.4.1). Names introduced by using declarations should be found by unqualified lookup instead of ADL. I think this is correctly implemented in the compilers I checked, Clang, GCC 4.5, and VS11. http://ideone.com/YPl2J

Comment: @bames53: interesting: I was fairly sure that operator hijacking was made hard but you are right: rereading the paragraph shows the operator should be found. Since there is already `std::basic_istream<cT, Tr>::operator>>(char*)` it make it quite unclear what is going on: http://ideone.com/nBtzx Thanks for clarifying.

Comment: @DietmarKühl `f()` isn't finding your operator because the location of the declaration makes it invisible to `f()`.

Comment: I know. The point of this example is that identical code in the same translation unit changed its meaning without any if the involved types being defined locally. I realize that there are other examples but things like this make it hard to predict what's going on.

Comment: @DietmarKühl Oh I see. By "it makes it quite unclear what is going on" you didn't mean it was unclear to you, just that the code is less readable. Yeah, it's probably best to avoid this by not overloading in the global namespace, especially not operators. I'll note that in my 'answer'.

Answer (score 2):

Are you sure you're including util.h in the file where you do 'file >> "[ "'?

Without more detail it's difficult to tell what problem you're running into. For me clang compiles just fine with the following complete program:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <sstream>

std::istream& operator>>(std::istream& is, const char *str);
std::istream& operator>>(std::istream& is, char *str);

int main() {
    std::stringstream file("tmp");
    char *x, *y;

    // opening and allocating space for strings comes here

    file >> "[ " >> x >> "," >> y >> " ]";
}


// util.cpp
//
// lots of stuff again

void parse(std::istream& is, const char *str) {}

//! a global operator to scan (parse) strings from a stream
std::istream& operator>>(std::istream& is, const char *str){
    parse(is, str); return is;
}
//! the same global operator for non-const string
std::istream& operator>>(std::istream& is, char *str){
    parse(is, (const char*)str); return is;
}
```

---

Though you should consider doing this in some other way, because providing your own overloaded operator to override a standard one is not a good practice. The rules for lookup are arcane and code that abuses them will probably be difficult to understand and maintain.

Comment: Yes, this minimal example compiles. So probably some other thing in our files magically obscures the operator overloading.
The codebase is actually old, so changing this operator overload would break a lot.

Comment: @hildensia If you can provide a (small) program that reproduces the issue I may be able to provide a better answer.

Comment: I'll try to get an example, but it may take some time, since I'm occupied right now.

Comment: not an example, but some new information: clang can find the right operator if I use `::operator>>(is, "[");`